# Write to event log from a driver

Tags: c, driver, event-log

I want to write to the event log from a driver.
I know that i need to use [IoAllocateErrorLogEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I also added the registry key

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\driverName

Now I want to set the source of the log to be the "driverName".
I tried to follow the "write log" instruction in [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/writing_devicedriver.html) but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I write to the event log with a specific source?

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't forget to register source as  [Registering as a Source of Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560866(v=vs.85).aspx)

2)Don't leave spaces between iologmsg.dll and your driver in registry

3) Sometimes you will need to reboot after driver installation to see canges

And all will work!